# How can I organize in Unity's hierarchy GameObjects that are spawned in a nested structure?

Tags: unity, gameobject, hierarchy

I'm wondering how I can organize instantiated GameObjects that are spawned in sort of a nested structure. I'm spawning these GameObjects via `Container`s, a set of classes that either spawn the GameObjects directly, or spawn other `Container`s with some kind of logic. I want to be able to spawn a number of `Container`s, and then spawn a parent in the Unity hierarchy to which each of the GameObjects spawned by these containers will be parented. However, some `Container`s will also be parented to other `Container`s, creating this kind of structure:

```
Container
    Container
        Prefab
        Prefab
    Container
        Prefab
        Prefab
```

For example, I may have classes like these:

```
public abstract class Container : ScriptableObject
{
     public static event Action<Container> OnContainerSpawned;

     public abstract void Spawn(Vector2 position);

     protected void RaiseSpawnEvent(Container container)
     {
        OnContainerSpawned(container);
     }
}

// Spawns a single prefab; this is the smallest "unit" in my system
public class GameObjectContainer: Container
{
    public static event Action<GameObject> OnGameObjectSpawned;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject prefab;
    
    public override void Spawn(Vector2 position)
    {
        var spawnedPrefab = Instantiate(prefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
        OnGameObjectSpawned?.Invoke(spawnedPrefab);
        RaiseSpawnEvent(this);
    }
}

// Spawns a container in a row
public class RowContainer : Container
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Container container;  
    [SerializeField]
    private int length;  

    public override void Spawn(Vector2 position)
    {
        var spawnPosition = position;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            container.Spawn(spawnPosition);
            spawnPosition += Vector2.right;
        }

        RaiseSpawnEvent(this);
    }
}

// Spawns a container in a column
public class ColumnContainer: Container
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Container container;  
    [SerializeField]
    private int length;  

    public override void Spawn(Vector2 position)
    {
        var spawnPosition = position;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            container.Spawn(spawnPosition);
            spawnPosition += Vector2.down;
        }

        RaiseSpawnEvent(this);
    }
}
```

I'm currently using events to alert my debugging class that something has been spawned so that it can parent things accordingly:

```
public class Debugger : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject prefabParent;

    private List<GameObjects> recentlySpawnedGameObjects = new List<GameObject>();

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        Container.OnContainerSpawned += TrackSpawns;
        GameObjectContainer.OnGameObjectSpawned += recentlySpawnedGameObjects.Add;
    }

    private void TrackSpawns(Container container)
    {
        if (container is GameObjectContainer) // Don't bother making a parent for a single GameObject
            return;

        // Make a new parent in the hierarchy, and update its name
        var parent = Instantiate(prefabParent); 
        parent.name = container.name;
        
        // Parent each recently spawned GameObject (from the event in the GameObjectContainer class) to the parent we just created
        foreach (var gameObject in recentlySpawnedGameObjects)
            gameObject.transform.parent = parent;

        // Clear the list, and await next container to spawn
        recentlySpawnedGameObjects.Clear();
    }
}
```

This might produce a result that looks like this:

```
Row Container
    GameObject
    GameObject
    GameObject
```

This is fine, but it only shows the topmost `Container`. What if I have a `RowContainer` that spawns a `ColumnContainer` that spawns a `GameObjectContainer`, attempting to get something that looks like this:

```
Row Container
    Column Container
        GameObject
        GameObject
        GameObject
    Column Container
        GameObject
        GameObject
        GameObject
    Column Container
        GameObject
        GameObject
        GameObject
```

I have no idea how to achieve this. In my actual game I'm spawning things using object pools, so I only need to track the pooled objects and reuse them as necessary, which I can do. However, it would be very nice to debug my system in this way, creating an easy-to-understand visual, especially as my game becomes more complex.

Comment: Didyou took a look at the description of the overload parameter for `Instantiate`? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html All you need to do is pass the parent, under which it should be.

Comment: As I mentioned in the last bit of my question, I'm using pooled objects in my actual game, so I'm not instantiating most of the time, just moving around pre-instantianted objects. I need a solution that works in that context, so I can't use the `Instantiate` method to assign a parent.